# Undefined index error in importing excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to import my excel to my database but the problem is that theres an error saying "Undefined index: title" referring to the title in the controller. 
So this is my code for my controller

```
    public function importExcel()
{
    if(Input::hasFile('import_file')){
        $path = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath();
        $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader){
        })->get();
        if(!empty($insert)){
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $insert[] = ['title' => $value->title, 'description' => $value->description];
            }
        if(!empty($insert)){
            DB::table('items')->insert($insert);
            print_r('Insert Record succesfully');
        }
        }
    }
    return back();
}
```

And this is for my view blade:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <a href="{{ URL::to('downloadExcel/xls') }}"><button class="btn btn-success">Download Excel xls</button></a>
    <a href="{{ URL::to('downloadExcel/xlsx') }}"><button class="btn btn-success">Download Excel xlsx</button></a>
    <a href="{{ URL::to('downloadExcel/csv') }}"><button class="btn btn-success">Download CSV</button></a>
    <form style="border: 4px solid #a1a1a1;margin-top: 15px;padding: 10px;" action="{{ URL::to('importExcel') }}" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="file" name="import_file" />
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Import File</button>
    </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

Here is the image of the excel i want to upload to my database. It's an xlsx that i want to upload.
[See picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn5U0.png)

But the error says like this [Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xsAL.png)

Comment: can you please show the output of $reader

Comment: @vikalp sorry i changed my code, can you check thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the sheet data directly by calling the `toArray` method of the `Maatwebsite\Excel\Readers\LaravelExcelReader`.

```
$loadedFile = Excel::load($path);
$inserts = $loadedFile->toArray(); 

if (!empty($insert)) {
    DB::table('items')->insert($insert);
    print_r('Inserted Record successfully');
}
```

However, going by your implementation it should be noted that when a callback is specified for the reader, `$reader->all()` or `$reader->get()` returns a `Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\RowCollection` or  `Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\SheetCollection` depending on the amount of sheets the file has.

For your sample where there is a single sheet, you can rightly expect a `Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\RowCollection`. Therefore you have

```
$inserts = [];
Excel::load($path, function($reader) use (&$inserts) {
    foreach ($reader->get() as $row) {
        $inserts[] = ['title' => $row->title, 'description' => $row->description];
    }    
});

if (!empty($inserts)) {
    DB::table('items')->insert($inserts);
    print_r('Inserted Record successfully');
}
```

Comment: Theres an error "Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance." @Oluwafemi Sule

Comment: What is dumped when you  `dd($row);` inside of the `foreach` loop before appending to `$inserts` array.